# Extbase: select child objects depending on date

Tags: typo3

2 Tables: seminars, dates, 1:n connection with irre (inline)

Is there a possibility to get all seminars in a list and for every seminar all dates which ar newer than today.

Getting all seminars with all their dates is easy. But i cant find a possibilty to restrict the child objects to certain conditions. And of course to sort them ...

Is there a possibilty aside from raw sql-queries?

Thanks
Petrer

Comment: Do you use extbase?

Comment: Yes, i do. I cannot find a way to filter or sort the extbase objects ... (child objects of course; sorting or filter the main objects is easy. TYPO3 8 LTS)

Comment: There exist three possibilities to connect to DB: 1) extbase with it's own API, 2) Doctrine Dbal implementation in TYPO3 core which is more open but still with some restrictions, 3) directly Doctrine Dbal without TYPO3 wrapper is most free to use, i.e. there it's easy to physically delete records which is hard or impossible with the other solutions.